# Tautology or contradiction without a truth table

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to find out whether $\big(\neg a\implies(b\implies c)\big)\Leftrightarrow\big(b\implies(a\lor c)\big)$ is a tautology or contradiction without using a truth table, but I'm unsure how to start...?

Comment: Do you know how write $b\implies c$ using $\land$ and $\lor$?

Comment: Because you cannot use a truth table, you'll want to apply equivalences until you derive that this is a tautology or a contradiction. A good thing to start with would be to use the definition of $\rightarrow$ and replace all arrows with OR's and NOT's. Also replace the double-arrow with it's definition. You'll obtain a formula with only OR's, AND's and NOT's. This formula can now be reduced using basic equivalences.

Answer (score 0):

(b implies a or c) iff
(b implies (not a implies c)) iff
((b and not a) implies c) iff
not a implies (b implies c)